# Angular - Using ngFor on a select input is causing strange behavior

Tags: angular

I have a very simple, or so I thought, select input. It is getting its values for the `option` tags by using `ngFor`. I also am using `[selected]` to set the value of the input based on what the user has selected.

**The Behavior:**

When I click on the dropdown, it is flashing like it is loading or doing something twice. It doesn't have the normal opening event like I remember seeing. Once it is open, I can pick a value just fine. If I go back and re-open the options again, it is setting the selected option back to what is currently selected in the object. <--- This may be normal behavior since I am telling it what `selected` should be. Ideally though, this should be set one time and then not reset each time it is opened.

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" *ngIf="inEditMode(r.RuleParentID, a.AttributeID)" (change)="updateOperator($event)">
  <option value="">Select Operator</option>
  <option *ngFor="let o of fetchOperatorList(a.AttributeID)" [value]="o.OperatorID" [selected]="o.OperatorID === a.OperatorID">{{ o.OperatorName }}</option>
</select>
```

**fetchOperatorList() method:**

```
fetchOperatorList(attributeID) {

        let temp = Array();

        // Scan our attributes
        for (const key in this.globalMapData.attributes) {

            // Find attribute by property
            if (this.globalMapData.attributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                // If this attribute is the one we are searching, continue
                if (this.globalMapData.attributes[key].AttributeID == attributeID) {

                    // Loop over the operators for this attribute
                    let ops = this.globalMapData.attributes[key].attributeOperators.a;
                    for (var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++) {

                        // Push possible attribute operators to an array
                        temp.push({
                            OperatorID: ops[i].OperatorID,
                            OperatorName: ops[i].OperatorName,
                            SqlOperator: ops[i].SqlOperator
                        });

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

**Example Image:**

[image]

**Goal:**

First, I have no idea why it is doing the whole appearance of double loading, seems off...

Is there also a way to set the default selected value but not reset it back every time the input is opened? To get to this point, the user clicked "Edit" on the page and was provided the `select` to change the option. If they happen to pick the wrong thing and open it again, I don't want it to reset back to the original.

**Update:**

I removed the `ngIf` on the select itself as well as the `onChange` to help narrow it down. The issue still occurs. I removed the `selected` property and only kept `[value]`. I put in a `console.log` in the `ngFor` function and thats where it was interesting. It appears to be running two times, multiple times. I am going to look at this function a little more and see what is being output but that's gotta be part of the problem.

**Update2:**

This select is wrapped within another `ngFor` that is looping over all of my user records. What appears to be happening is when the `ngIf` becomes true, it calls the `ngFor` on the select `options` for the number of times it was iterated over.

```
<tr class="attribute" *ngFor="let a of r.attributes.attribute" [class.info]="inEditMode(r.RuleParentID, a.AttributeID)">
 <td class="small col-md-2 attr"><strong>{{ a.AttributeName }}</strong></td>
 <td class="small col-md-1 oper">
   <span *ngIf="!inEditMode(r.RuleParentID, a.AttributeID)">
    <strong>{{ a.OperatorName}}</strong>
   </span>
   <select class="form-control input-sm" *ngIf="inEditMode(r.RuleParentID, a.AttributeID)">
   <option value="">Select Operator</option>
     <option *ngFor="let o of fetchOperatorList(a.AttributeID)" [value]="o.OperatorID">{{ o.OperatorName }}</option>
   </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What happend if you remove the *ngIf* on the select? could you try?

Comment: Don't use `[selected]` in the option tag, use `[value]` in select tag (e.g. `[value]="a.OperatorID"`

Comment: try to debug how many times fetchOperatorList runs. Guess it runs multiple times.

Comment: why not go with `ngModel` and remove the selected attribute and check also dont use change then use `ngModelChange`

Comment: I am working on getting it debugged per suggestions, server issue causing a problem. @RahulSingh I tried this and needed a different solution. I am updating my data object and need to modify multiple values at once. When I used ngModel, I could only update the object's ID with the value of the select item. My object also has a text value that I need to update as well. The onChange seemed to be the better route in order to update multiple data points in my object at once based on the value selected.

Comment: @SBB `(change)="updateOperator($event)"` What is the this method doing. Are you updating the list of options on change of select in the updateOperator method? If yes  this might be the issue. Try removing this method and see if it behaves the same.

Comment: @alexKhymenko - I added some additional information as to why I think this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this happens in development mode, it's because angular's changedetection is running twice for each change. This is likely causing the flash, because you're creating a new reference of the array and the `ngForOf` directive is reflecting that. You could try to tell the `ngForOf` directive to track it's children by index without taking the reference into account via `trackBy` and a function.

```
trackByIndex(index: number, value: any) {
  return index;
}
```

And inside your template:

```
*ngFor="...;trackBy:trackByIndex"
```

Comment: So this appeared to fix the flashing, however, when I expand the select, the `ngFor` on the `<option>` tag is firing the `fetchOperatorList()` the number of times that the parent iterated over the select element. For example in Update#2, the `tr` looped 10 times over the select. When I put a `console.log` inside the `fetchOoperatorList()`, it is firing 10 times to reflect that, even though this is the only select with the `ngIf` being `true` on my page. The other 9, the `ngIf` is false and are not visible.

Comment: If i understand your update #2 correctly, that's the expected behavior. In your example you're creating 10 `<select>` elements with `option` elements as children and apply the `ngForOf` directive to them by getting it's value from `fetchOoperatorList`. Therefore `fetchOoperatorList` should be called 10 times.

Comment: I guess I assumed that there was some type of scope to the `ngFor` loop in that  the element I am interacting with (the select) is specific to that of the data it was given by the parent for that iteration and not all 10 of them. How would I even approach something like this, im sure nested `ngFor`s are common.